# OnePage Scroll custom nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I built this website http://www.graphink.be where I use the OnepageScroll Plugin. 
I came across the weirdest behaviour with the plugin.

I hooked a custom navigation to the scroll effect.

When I click the nav links, following DOWN the sections, the plugin will automatically skip one section at each click.

Meaning : click on the 2nd link, it will move to the 3rd, click on the 3rd and it will move on to the 4th and so on, creating a blank section when clicking on the last link.

The weirdest thing is that it seems to be working fine following UP the links...

here's the small js I created for the custom nav:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("nav > input").click(function(){
$(".content").moveTo($(this).data("target"));
});


// Set up nav bar
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $("#logo").on('click', function(){$(".content").moveTo(1);});
    $(".arrow").on('click', function(){
        $(".content").moveDown();
    }); 
    $("#nav_home").on('click ', function(){$(".content").moveTo(1); });
    $("#nav_work").on('click ', function(){$(".content").moveTo(2);});
    $("#nav_about").on('click ', function(){    $(".content").moveTo(3);    });
    $("#nav_contact").on('click ', function(){$(".content").moveTo(4);});

});
```

I obviously made a mistake somewhere, but I just can't find it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the section index starts on 0. As it always does in javascript or jquery. Although it's not very clear in the docs...

> **$.fn.moveTo(page_index)**
>
> This method allows you to move to the specified **page index** programatically.

Change the `data-target` attribute to one number less on each.

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#intro" id="nav_home" data-target="0">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#work" id="nav_work" data-target="1">Work</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#about" id="nav_about" data-target="2">About</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#contact" id="nav_contact" data-target="3">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you still having troubles, I would recommend you to try [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) which integrates a `menu` option and many other useful options and configurations.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, 

Thanks for your answer ! 
I took your advice, and changed the whole thing to FullPage.js... Seems to be working now ! 

Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome! Do not forget to accept the answer if it was valid for you, as it might be for someone else in the future as well ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try getting the section index from the element clicked and make sure the index is always correct:

```
$('nav li a').click(function(e) {
    var sectionIndex = $(this).data("target");
    console.log(sectionIndex); // print to check
    $('.content').moveTo(sectionIndex);
});
```

Comment: Hi ! 
Thanks for your response! 

I just tried, and it didn't work. 
What's frustrating is that it works in one way, and not the other... So i guess it means the markup is right... right ? 

Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with href attribute of "a"
Try to remove #intro #work #contact and #about from "a" elements of your navigation

Comment: Thank you for your response !! 

I tried removing href from every 'a'. Didn't work... :-/

I'm lost... any idea ?